# How to get the outlook-recipient details using VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a list of recipients (or Email addresses) on Excel. Is there a way to get their details using Outlook.Application  and/or Outlook.MailItem and VBA ?

Here is a function showing the Department of the recipient :

```
Public Function Get_Department_Name(ByVal Recipient As String)
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem
    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)    
    With NewMail
         .Subject = "Test Subject"
         .To = Recipient
         .Body = " Body of Message "
    End With
Get_Department_Name  = NewMail.Recipients.Item(1).AddressEntry.Manager().Department

    NewMail.Delete
   Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Function
```

I however did not manage to get :

1)Corporate title e.g. Associate Director , Vice President ...etc.

2)Organization details e.g. "Customer Services" , "Human Resources" ...etc.

Comment: Yes there is. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you [Google your exact question](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+get+the+outlook-recipient+details+using+VBA%2FExcel), myriad results come up. Surely you've tried some and have some code to show us, and comments on what's working and what's not?  You should know that some effort is expected here on SO before asking questions. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I think you will have to use AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Method (Outlook).Returns an ExchangeUser object that represents the AddressEntry if the AddressEntry belongs to an Exchange AddressList object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user.You have to be connected to the Exchange server to use this method.Then you can get ` Debug.Print (oExUser.JobTitle) 
 
 Debug.Print (oExUser.OfficeLocation) 
 
 Debug.Print (oExUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber) ` etc, <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser>

Comment: GetExchangeUser works perfect. Thanks heaps !

Comment: @DKK Glad that you could workout a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function gets the JobTitle/departement needed, this is using AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Method (Outlook).

```
Public Function Get_JobTitle(ByVal Recipient As String)
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With NewMail
         .Subject = Date & " Test Email"
         .To = Recipient
    End With

Get_JobTitle = NewMail.Recipients.Item(1).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.JobTitle
' Can replace JobTitle by  department
    NewMail.Delete
   Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing

End Function
```